# position of WHERE clause in sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have generated an sql to query a database table where posts from users are saved.But I am getting error executing it.I have tested it [here](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) , It also tells me that it is incorrect and the problem lies in **users_user_id** section.I can't figure out what might be wrong here.Can any one help me with this error.

My userpost table structure is following:

> post_id,post,title,users_user_id

***sql:***

```
SELECT title FROM userpost LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10 WHERE users_user_id=9
```

Comment: limit and offset go behind the where

Comment: it is not being executed.no specific error is mentioned ,You can test the sql in the link i have provided

Comment: `SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9  LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10`

Comment: enough downvote for today :|

Comment: 9 identical answers - perhaps check before answering

Comment: You also could have looked at the syntax for `select`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIMIT` always come after all keywords.

Corrected SQL:

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Generally, SELECT query has following sequence:

```
SELECT
Fields List
FROM
WHERE 
GROUP BY (if needed)
ORDER BY (if needed)
LIMIT (This always come at end and if limit is not specified, 
query will return all records from result set.)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set offset with limit as per below-

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 10, 5;
```

Where after limit first argumet is offset and 2nd is for no. of record means limit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way :

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

where clause use after from.

Answer (score 2):

Write your `where condition` first then use `limit`. LIMIT always come after all keywords.

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 2):

`where` should be use before `limit`

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
SELECT title FROM userpost LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10 WHERE users_user_id=9
```

to:

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 2):

limit should be after where condition

```
 SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 2):

LIMIT always come at last position

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5,10
```

I hope this will work

Comment: It should be limit 10, 5 and not 5, 10.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your Query.  Always `where condition` place before `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id = 9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way
And `LIMIT` should be after where condition

```
SELECT title FROM userpost WHERE users_user_id=9 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```